# C++ - Creating Geometry

Tags: c++, visual-studio, geometry, cube, scenegraph

I have been given an assignment at uni to compile the code given to us and identify:

- **Type of OpenGL primitives which have been used.**
- **How many primitives have been created.**
- **How many vertices have been created.**
- **Properties of the mesh.**

The code given to us is supposed to create a cube, however it does not. I've been looking through it for hours now and cannot figure out why.

I thought it might have been because "*createCube()*" was not mentioned in main at all, so i added "*scene = createCube();*"
However at first this gave me an error, *createCube() has not been defined*. After hours of messing about with it, i no longer get this error although there's still no cube. I just get an empty window.

It wouldn't matter that it doesn't work as I could answer the questions without seeing the cube, however the next part of the assignment is to create a Tetrahedron rather than a cube and for that I need the code to work.

If anybody can see what I'm missing, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Geometry
//
// This tutorial supports learning
// about assembling a scene in a scene graph
// using transformation cores

// headers for OpenSG configuration and GLUT
#include <OpenSG/OSGGLUT.h>
#include <OpenSG/OSGConfig.h>
#include <OpenSG/OSGSimpleGeometry.h>
#include <OpenSG/OSGGLUTWindow.h>
#include <OpenSG/OSGSimpleSceneManager.h>
#include <OpenSG/OSGSceneFileHandler.h>
#include <OpenSG/OSGGeoProperties.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

// Simple Scene manager for accesing cameras and geometry
OSG::SimpleSceneManagerRefPtr mgr;

int setupGLUT(int *argc, char *argv[]);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    // initialise OpenSG
    OSG::osgInit(argc, argv);

    // initialise GLUT
    int winid = setupGLUT(&argc, argv);

    {
        // create a OSGGLUT window
        OSG::GLUTWindowRefPtr gwin = OSG::GLUTWindow::create();
        gwin->setGlutId(winid);
        gwin->init();


        //read the file which will be passed as an argument
        OSG::NodeRefPtr scene = OSG::Node::create();
        OSG::NodeRefPtr createCube = OSG::Node::create();
        scene = createCube;

        //commit all changes to OpenSG 
        OSG::commitChanges();

        // create the SimpleSceneManager helper
        mgr = OSG::SimpleSceneManager::create();

        // tell the manager what to manage
        mgr->setWindow(gwin);
        mgr->setRoot(scene);
        // show the whole scene
        mgr->showAll();
    }
    // GLUT main loop
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

//
// GLUT callback functions
//

// redraw the window
void display(void)
{
    mgr->redraw();
}

// react to size changes
void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    mgr->resize(w, h);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

// react to mouse button presses
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if (!state)
        mgr->mouseButtonPress(button, x, y);

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

// react to mouse motions with pressed buttons
void motion(int x, int y)
{
    mgr->mouseMove(x, y);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

// react to keys
void keyboard(unsigned char k, int x, int y)
{
    switch (k)
    {
    case 'e':
    {
        // clean up global variables
        mgr = NULL;

        OSG::osgExit();
        exit(0);
    }
    break;
    case 's':
    {
        mgr->setStatistics(!mgr->getStatistics());
    }
    break;
    }
}

// setup the GLUT library which handles the windows for us
int setupGLUT(int *argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);

    int winid = glutCreateWindow("05 Transformations Tutorial");

    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMotionFunc(motion);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);

    return winid;
}
OSG::NodeRefPtr createCube()
{
    //create a node to hold the geometry
    OSG::NodeRefPtr geonode = OSG::Node::create();

    //create a geometry
    OSG::GeometryRefPtr geo = OSG::Geometry::create();

    //The primitive types.
    //OpenGL provides us with several different types of shapes that we can     draw 
    //(e.g. GL_LINES, GL_POLYGON, GL_QUADS, GL_TRIANGLES)
    //we need to specify the type of geometry we want to use
    //lets start by using only triangles (although different types can be     freely mixed)
    OSG::GeoUInt8PropertyRefPtr type = OSG::GeoUInt8Property::create();
    //MODIFY HERE 
    type->addValue(GL_TRIANGLES);

    //The primitive lengths.
        //These define the number of vertices to be passed to OpenGL for     each primitive. 
        //Thus there have to be at least as many entries as in the types     property.
    //in the case of the cube we are using 12 triangles which each have 3     vertices (12 X 3 = 36) 
    OSG::GeoUInt32PropertyRefPtr lens = OSG::GeoUInt32Property::create();
    //MODIFY HERE 
    lens->addValue(36);


    // The vertices.
    OSG::GeoPnt3fPropertyRefPtr  pnts = OSG::GeoPnt3fProperty::create();
    //MODIFY HERE with positions of your geometry
    pnts->addValue(OSG::Pnt3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5));
    pnts->addValue(OSG::Pnt3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5));
    pnts->addValue(OSG::Pnt3f(0.5, -0.5, 0.5));
    pnts->addValue(OSG::Pnt3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5));
    pnts->addValue(OSG::Pnt3f(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5));
    pnts->addValue(OSG::Pnt3f(0.5, 0.5, -0.5));
    pnts->addValue(OSG::Pnt3f(0.5, -0.5, -0.5));
    pnts->addValue(OSG::Pnt3f(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5));

    // The normals.
    //These are used for lighting calculations and have to point away from     the
    //surface. Normals are standard vectors. 
    OSG::GeoVec3fPropertyRefPtr  norms = OSG::GeoVec3fProperty::create();
    norms->push_back(OSG::Vec3f(0, 0, 1));
    norms->push_back(OSG::Vec3f(1, 0, 0));
    norms->push_back(OSG::Vec3f(0, 0, -1));
    norms->push_back(OSG::Vec3f(-1, 0, 0));
    norms->push_back(OSG::Vec3f(0, 1, 0));
    norms->push_back(OSG::Vec3f(0, -1, 0));

    // The colours.   
    // GeoColor3fProperty stores all color values that will be used
    OSG::GeoColor3fPropertyRecPtr colors =     OSG::GeoColor3fProperty::create();
    colors->addValue(OSG::Color3f(0, 0, 1));
    colors->addValue(OSG::Color3f(0, 0, 1));
    colors->addValue(OSG::Color3f(0, 0, 1));
    colors->addValue(OSG::Color3f(0, 0, 1));
    colors->addValue(OSG::Color3f(0, 0, 1));
    colors->addValue(OSG::Color3f(0, 0, 1));

    // The indices.
    // in order not to replicate the same positions all the time, 
    // use index number of the position 
    OSG::GeoUInt32PropertyRefPtr indices = OSG::GeoUInt32Property::create();

    //face 1: front 
    //face 1 - triangle 1
    indices->addValue(0);
    indices->addValue(2);
    indices->addValue(1);
    //face 1 - triangle 2
    indices->addValue(0);
    indices->addValue(3);
    indices->addValue(2);


    //face 2: right 
    //face 2 - triangle 1
    indices->addValue(1);
    indices->addValue(2);
    indices->addValue(6);
    //face 3 - triangle 2
    indices->addValue(1);
    indices->addValue(6);
    indices->addValue(5);


    //face 3: back
    //face 3 - triangle 1
    indices->addValue(5);
    indices->addValue(6);
    indices->addValue(7);
    //face 3 - triangle 2
    indices->addValue(5);
    indices->addValue(7);
    indices->addValue(4);


    //face 4: left
    //face 4 - triangle 1
    indices->addValue(4);
    indices->addValue(7);
    indices->addValue(3);
    //face 4 - triangle 2
    indices->addValue(4);
    indices->addValue(3);
    indices->addValue(0);

    //face 5: top
    //face 5 - triangle 1
    indices->addValue(4);
    indices->addValue(1);
    indices->addValue(5);
    //face 5 - triangle 2
    indices->addValue(4);
    indices->addValue(0);
    indices->addValue(1);

    //face 6: bottom
    //face 6 - triangle 1
    indices->addValue(2);
    indices->addValue(3);
    indices->addValue(7);
    //face 6 - triangle 2
    indices->addValue(2);
    indices->addValue(7);
    indices->addValue(6);


    // The indices for colours and normals
    // as normals are different for each side of the cube, we use a special         index for this property
    OSG::GeoUInt32PropertyRefPtr indicesnormpos =     OSG::GeoUInt32Property::create();
    //face 1: front 
    //face 1 - triangle 1
    indicesnormpos->addValue(0);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(0);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(0);
    //face 1 - triangle 2
    indicesnormpos->addValue(0);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(0);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(0);


    //face 2: right 
    //face 2 - triangle 1
    indicesnormpos->addValue(1);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(1);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(1);
    //face 3 - triangle 2
    indicesnormpos->addValue(1);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(1);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(1);


    //face 3: back
    //face 3 - triangle 1
    indicesnormpos->addValue(2);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(2);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(2);
    //face 3 - triangle 2
    indicesnormpos->addValue(2);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(2);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(2);


    //face 4: left
    //face 4 - triangle 1
    indicesnormpos->addValue(3);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(3);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(3);
    //face 4 - triangle 2
    indicesnormpos->addValue(3);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(3);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(3);

    //face 5: top
    //face 5 - triangle 1
    indicesnormpos->addValue(4);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(4);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(4);
    //face 5 - triangle 2
    indicesnormpos->addValue(4);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(4);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(4);

    //face 6: bottom
    //face 6 - triangle 1
    indicesnormpos->addValue(5);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(5);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(5);
    //face 6 - triangle 2
    indicesnormpos->addValue(5);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(5);
    indicesnormpos->addValue(5);

    // Put it all together into a Geometry NodeCore.
    geo->setTypes(type);
    geo->setLengths(lens);

    geo->setProperty(pnts, OSG::Geometry::PositionsIndex);
    geo->setIndex(indices, OSG::Geometry::PositionsIndex);

    geo->setProperty(norms, OSG::Geometry::NormalsIndex);
    geo->setIndex(indicesnormpos, OSG::Geometry::NormalsIndex);

    geo->setProperty(colors, OSG::Geometry::ColorsIndex);
    geo->setIndex(indicesnormpos, OSG::Geometry::ColorsIndex);

    // if you were not using any indexing you will simply use:
    //geo->setTypes    (type);
    //geo->setLengths  (lens);
    //geo->setPositions (pnts);
    //geo->setNormals   (norms);
    //geo->setColors    (colors);        

    geonode->setCore(geo);

    return geonode;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `OSG::NodeRefPtr createCube()` isn't declared by when you called it in your main. So, just declare it:

```
OSG::NodeRefPtr createCube();
int setupGLUT(int *argc, char *argv[]);

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    // Rest of code
```

And, in your main:

```
    //read the file which will be passed as an argument
    OSG::NodeRefPtr scene = createCube();
```

You can delete the following statements:

```
    OSG::NodeRefPtr createCube = OSG::Node::create();
    scene = createCube;
```

Comment: Haha I knew it was because it wasn't defined above main. But when I tried, I got an error for having multiple definitions of 'createCube()', but this seems to have worked.
Thank you!!
(I'd vote the comment up, but having less than 15 rep, it doesn't count).

Comment: If this solved your problem, could you mark the answer as correct?